# Visual Code Definitely Types

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with my project **Visual Studio Code v. 0.10.6** using `Angular 1.4.x ES5`

. When i click on `angular` module it says:

```
typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts already exists. Make sure the file is included in the project's jsconfig.json
```

however, i have already configured my json file at the root of my project as shown below.

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "file": "typings/tsd.d.ts"

}
```

**tds.json**

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "angularjs/angular.d.ts": {
      "commit": "1cdd8bc01fc0bd0f22193e1dc9ad43635da4cd92"
    },
    "jquery/jquery.d.ts": {
      "commit": "1cdd8bc01fc0bd0f22193e1dc9ad43635da4cd92"
    }
  }
}
```

**typings/tsd.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

I would like to know what i am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: and what about your typings/tsd.d.ts file?

Comment: @rmjoia i have updated my question.

Comment: As of my knowledge, you usually don't have to reference .d.ts files. It will recognize them automatically and include those. If that doesn't work, could you kindly post your folder structure?